# Typography and spacing in material-ui

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I defined raw theme for `material-ui` in `theme.ts`:

```
import {Colors, Spacing} from 'material-ui/lib/styles/';
import {ColorManipulator} from 'material-ui/lib/utils/';
import {Styles} from 'material-ui';

export default <Styles.RawTheme> {
    spacing: Spacing,
    fontFamily: 'Roboto, sans-serif',
    palette: <Styles.ThemePalette> {
        primary1Color: Colors.red500,
        primary2Color: Colors.red700,
        primary3Color: Colors.lightBlack,
        accent1Color: Colors.orangeA200,
        accent2Color: Colors.grey100,
        accent3Color: Colors.grey500,
        textColor: Colors.darkBlack,
        alternateTextColor: Colors.white,
        canvasColor: Colors.white,
        borderColor: Colors.grey300,
        disabledColor: ColorManipulator.fade(Colors.darkBlack, 0.3),
        pickerHeaderColor: Colors.red500,
    }
};
```

Then in my custom React component `app.tsx` I applied this theme:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import {AppBar, AppCanvas} from 'material-ui';
import {ThemeManager, ThemeDecorator} from 'material-ui/lib/styles/';
import Theme from 'theme';

@ThemeDecorator(ThemeManager.getMuiTheme(Theme))
export class App extends React.Component<{}, {}> {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <AppBar title={ 'App' } showMenuIconButton={false}/>
                <AppCanvas>
                    <h1>Test</h1>
                </AppCanvas>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

But `h1` header is not styled as it has to be in Material design. No `Roboto` font, smaller size.

Does material-ui have built-in styles or something else that I can use to easily style headers according to Material guidelines and also give spacing (margins and padding) to elements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

material-ui now has [Typography](https://material-ui.com/components/typography/) component:

```
<Typography variant="h1" component="h2">
  h1. Heading
</Typography>
```

Also there are possibilities for [typography customizations](https://material-ui.com/customization/typography/) and [utilities](https://material-ui.com/system/typography/) to control alignment, wrapping, weight, and more.

**OLD ANSWER:**

material-ui 1.0 will come with `Typography` component: [usage](https://material-ui-next.com/style/typography/) and [API](https://material-ui-next.com/api/typography/).

You can try it right now by installing `material-ui@next`:

```
npm install material-ui@next --save
```

Answer (score 3):

Material-UI does not include the Roboto font, [it is up to you to include it in your project](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui#roboto-font).

Quickly verify this by adding the following in the `<head>` element of your HTML and checking if your `h1` header is styled:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500" rel="stylesheet">
```

If you want to download the Roboto font and include it in your static assets, you can get it from here: https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/roboto

Comment: Thanks. I upvoted. By I looked for implementation for typography styles from https://material.io/guidelines/style/typography.html#typography-styles. I already made some workaround. Will try to share it later.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how font size is calculated in the final theme, but if it's a function of the content in spacing, then you can manipulate that by adding a spacing section to your raw theme like this:

```
export default <Styles.RawTheme> {
    fontFamily: 'Roboto, sans-serif',
    spacing: {
      iconSize: 24,
      desktopGutter: 24,
      desktopGutterMore: 32,
      desktopGutterLess: 16,
      desktopGutterMini: 8,
      desktopKeylineIncrement: 60,  // left-nav width = this * 4
      desktopDropDownMenuItemHeight: 32,
      desktopDropDownMenuFontSize: 15,
      desktopLeftNavMenuItemHeight: 30,
      desktopSubheaderHeight: 48,
      desktopToolbarHeight: 56
    },
    palette: {...}
}
```

and play with those settings.